# Ubuntu 18.10 not adding gamepad device because it isn't a dualshock 4

Tags: bluetooth, games, 18.10, gamepad

I have an 8bitdo bluetooth controller, when I connect it to my pc (kubunut 18.10) it isn't added as a device though it does show in the bluetooth settings as connected gamepad.  Here's the messages out of sys log:

```
Can't get HIDP connection info
bluetoothd[1024]: connect error: Host is down (112)
kernel: [ 1769.693336] sony 0005:054C:05C4.0008: unknown main item tag 0x0
kernel: [ 1769.728118] sony 0005:054C:05C4.0008: Failed to get calibration data from Dualshock 4
kernel: [ 1769.728366] sony 0005:054C:05C4.0008: hidraw4: BLUETOOTH HID Gamepad [Wireless Controller] on c0:18:85:dd:65:6c
kernel: [ 1769.728369] sony 0005:054C:05C4.0008: failed to claim input
```

I imagine it's detecting it as a gamecontoller and trying to add the device as a dualshock 4 but because it isn't one it fails... Could anyone offer me any advice please?  I'm hoping to use it in Steam.

Answer (score 1):

I have plugged in the controller with a usb cable and I then did `$ fwupdmgr get updates` followed bu `$ fwupdmgr update`.  - I reconnected via bluetooth and this time the controller came up as 8BitDo... whoot!

Comment: That had no effect here... what's supposed to happen / how?